# SharePoint 2013 Workflows working for one site but not the other

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

What my workflow does is that when creating a new Task and I fill the Assigned To,
the workflow sends a mail to the Assigned To user.

On a site I got the workflow working and still working. But not on the identical another site.

It is just stuck on starting.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: check if you have edit permission on target and if you are a "service account" in right/top of page

Comment: As logged in user?

Comment: How did you move the workflow from one site to other?

Comment: yes, the logged user. He is as sevice acc?

Comment: Ofcourse he is. I've even tried with the farmadmin. I created a new subsite without the template and it worked. Now im trying to do a completely new subsite and save it to template then try the same thing.